# R data.frame Converts mix datatypes to factor

Tags: r

Why is data.frame changes my mixed data types to factor?

```
tempC=data.frame(A="a",B=22,C=T)
class(tempC$A)
[1] "factor"
```

It is fine when I use list, I thought data.frame is list.

```
tempD=list(A="a",B=22,C=T)
> class(tempD$A)
[1] "character"
```

What is the easiest way to put mixed datatype in a dataframe? Thanks,

Comment: You have to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as the default is `TRUE`

Comment: No problem.  If you use `data_frame` from `dplyr` or `data.table(A='a',...)`, the default will be `FALSE`